# spring Rest call through ajax

Tags: ajax, spring, rest, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

I am stuck with a problem when i send **POST** request through **ajax** to Spring Rest i am getting following error. But it is working fine with Postman tool.

How to solve this? Please help.

[image]

```
@RestController
public class LoginController {

    @Autowired
    LoginServiceBo loginServiceBo;

    public void setLoginServiceBo(LoginServiceBo loginServiceBo) {
        this.loginServiceBo = loginServiceBo;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/login",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView redirectLoginForm() {
        System.out.println("Login Page...");
        return new ModelAndView("login");
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/login",method=RequestMethod.POST, consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Login> login(@RequestBody Login login) {
        System.out.println("Checking Login Credentials...");
        boolean isValid=loginServiceBo.checkUserLogin(login);

        if(isValid) {
            System.out.println("Found...");
            return new ResponseEntity<Login>(login, HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
        }
        System.out.println("Not Found...");
        return new ResponseEntity<>(login, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);   
    }

}
```

In javascript

```
function RestPost() {
userId = document.getElementById("userId");
password = document.getElementById("password");
var json = {
    "userId": userId,
    "password": password
};

$.ajax({
    url: prefix + "/login",
    type: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify(json),
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    },
    success: function(response) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(response));


    },
    error: function(jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(jqXhr.status + ' ' + jqXhr.responseText);


    }
});
}
```

Comment: How can ajax request's response come to your browser directly? as you post the image of the error

Comment: i am doing alert() in that it must show response json

Comment: Yes, i have seen it in your code. But it seems like after post request. your page is loaded with the HTTP status (you screenshot of the error). Can you show your form including the button of you ajax call?

Comment: ya i changed code accordingly i got this error POST http://localhost:8073/Spring_Hibernate_Project_4.0/login 400 (Bad Request) and data is appended to url http://localhost:8073/Spring_Hibernate_Project_4.0/?uname=rohit&psw=abc123

Comment: <form>
  <div class="container">
    <label><b>Username</b></label>
    <input type="text" id="userId" placeholder="Enter Username" name="uname" required><br>

    <label><b>Password</b></label>
    <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" required><br>
        
    
    <button type="submit" onclick="RestPost()">Login</button><br>
    <span>Forgot <a href="#">password?</a></span>
  </div>  
</form>

Comment: remove the `type="submit" ` attribute from your `button` and try please. Or change the button as a link `<a href="#" onclick="RestPost()">Login</a>` then try.

Comment: i got HTTP status 404 The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect. but it is a valid json

Comment: 404 means NOT FOUND the URL